# Gamemaker studio 2 matchmaking

Tags: networking, logic, game-maker, gml, matchmaking

I just finished building a MOBA-like game in node.js for the web platform. Now I am planning on redoing it as an actual game in Game maker studio 2 while fixing some bugs and adding some new features. I ran into a problem a while back, however, I couldn't figure out the matchmaking (Game maker was my first choice but I switched to web because of this problem). I built the matchmaker in javascript as an array, however, I feel this will be problematic when there is a lot of players trying to find a game. I don't have any code in Game maker yet because if it is not relevant to do it I might try switching to a different game engine. 
**Matchmaking:**

  1) Like smite or league of legend, where you can accept or decline a match

  2) Someone in one game shouldn't be able to interact with another game.

I would really appreciate any help. I just need help understanding the logic for gamemaker because the networking is different and there is a room system.

Thank you very much!
Brandon Lacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the manual, networking part of. Also, GMNet engine exists, you may find it handy.

Comment: I don't know why I never thought of using an external library before. Thank you very much you fixed my problem in like 10 minutes.

Comment: You are welcome. Just please try to format your Q as per standard. Folks here can be extremely downvoting.. for almost nothing.

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to keep asking you questions but what was wrong with my question, was it not formal enough or was I just not specific?

Comment: I'd say it's too general. I don't mean to offend you but you should try to attach some code to prove you have put some effort into Q before asking. Like for example on my last Q folks gave me -7 cuz I havent attached sample code. Anyway, speaking of GMS2, you might found my engine useful: https://github.com/lofcz/SimplexRpgEngine

Comment: That wasn't offending, I had the feeling that might've come up though. I even put in that I hadn't started yet so I didn't have any code. But yes i will keep that in mind and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Foremore, I have some assets on store. If you find any of them useful just head me a message and you can have a copy for free: https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/publishers/3821/simplex